# В компонентах windows отсутствует флажок "Песочница Windows"

Tags: windows, windows-11

Я использую:
Выпуск  Windows 11 Домашняя
Версия  22H2
Сборка ОС   22621.1848
Взаимодействие  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22642.1000.0

Я решил включить Windows Sandbox и включил виртуализацию в биосе. Она включилась, но в компонентах виндовс не появилось флажка "Песочница Windows".
В диспетчере задач уже проверял, виртуализация точно включена.

Comment: а для неё pro версия нужна

Comment: @PavelGridin есть ли какой-то способ спиратить или вроде того?

Comment: ну есть же бесплатные виртуальные машины, Sandbox это просто hyper-v с windows в которой не сохраняется диск при перезагрузке